# Unable to update to hyperledger composer v 0.18.1

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm having trouble updating to the new version of hyperledger composer 0.18.1.

This is my work flow:

Uninstall the Hyperledger Composer components:

```
npm uninstall -g composer-cli
npm uninstall -g composer-rest-server
npm uninstall -g generator-hyperledger-composer
```

Instal the new version of composer:

```
    npm install -g composer-cli@next
    npm install -g composer-rest-server@next
    npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer@next
```

After I do this however if I do a:

```
composer -v
```

I get the following result:

```
composer -v
v0.16.5
```

Does anyone know why this is the case, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you try these commands: `which composer` and `npm ls -g --depth=0` .  Perhaps you have a version of composer installed in a specific folder - installed without -g, or perhaps included as a dependency for some sample or other application?

Comment: Thanks, RThatcher, I did something along those lines. I created a new directory. I then did the installation, getting the correct version of composer. I just cloned my repo and went from there :)